# Concerning a retraction $r : X\times I \to X\times \{0\} \cup A\times I$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

Let $A \subset X$ be a subset, where $I =[0,1]$.
I'd like to prove a suggestion that for any retraction $r : X\times I \to X\times \{0\} \cup A\times I$, if some $x\in X$ satisfies the condition $t=P_I \circ r (x,t)$ for all $t \in I$, where $P_I $ is the projection on $I$, then  $x \in A$.

It suffices to consider for the case  $x\in \bar{A} \setminus A$.
$X$ is a topological space not necessary to be Hausdorff.
How to prove this?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
For clarity, I edited my question.
Assume that $\bar{A}\setminus A \neq \emptyset$.
This question arises from Theorem 1.5 on page 431 in Bredon's Topology and Geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = \{0, 1\}$ with trivial indiscrete topology, let $A = \{1\}$, and let $r: X × I → X × \{0\} ∪ A × I$ be defined by $r(x, t) = (1, t)$ for $t > 0$ and $r(x, 0) = (x, 0)$. Then $r$ is a retraction. It is continuous since $P_I ∘ r = P_I$ and $P_X ∘ r$ is continuous trivially. Therefore, $r$ is a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: But I wonder the case $\bar{A}\setminus A \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @Jeong For $X$ with trivial topology, you can easily choose such $A$.

Comment: I think my statement have made a misunderstanding. So I modified it. Not for all $x \in X$ to satisfy $P_I \circ r = P_I$ but for some.

Comment: @Jeong: And I gave you a situation where the condition holds for every $x ∈ X$ and still a sufficient $A ⊊ X$ can be chosen. I'll add more detail on the example.